# Use more features of ES6(besides the shipped ones) in Node(for eg. "import/export")

Tags: node.js

## Objective

I am planning to start a web project with **reactJS + nodeJS + babel(ES6) + webpack**. But I am currently blocked at the step of ES6 environment setup.

## Tech Stack

- React: client-side (Views)
- Node:  server-side (Server)
- Babel: transpiler of ES6 -> ES5
- Webpack: module bundler

## Issue

**Cannot run some ES6 statements using node**

Steps to launch the app

> `$ npm install`
>
> `$ npm run build`
>
> `$ set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start`

Errortrace:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
        ... ...
```

## My Configurations

1. package.json

```
    {
      "name": "myapp",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "node ./bin/www"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "alt": "^0.18.2",
        "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
        "debug": "~2.2.0",
        "ejs": "^2.4.1",
        "express": "~4.13.1",
        "morgan": "~1.6.1",
        "react": "^0.14.7",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
        "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
        "webpack": "^1.12.14"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.0",
        "webpack": "^1.12.6",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
      }
    }
```

2. .babelrc

```
    { 
      "presets": [
        "es2015"
      ] 
    }
```

3. webpack.config.js
   [image]

## Project Repository

[click here](https://github.com/sbvictory/react-workout) hosted on Github

Answer (score 0):

Not all features of the ES6 are in production and enabled by default in nodejs. Modules are among one of them. You might need to run node.js with
*--harmony* flag, or specifically regarding modules: *--harmony_modules*

To see list of all 'in progress' features use the following command:

```
$ node --v8-options | grep 'in progress'
```